# (Matlab) Transform a vector into matrix by keeping the numbers by pairs

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, reshape

Let's say I have a vector that contains some coordinates (x,y) in this way:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

And I want to transform it in this matrix:

```
A = [1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10]
```

How can I do it? 'reshape' command is not what I'm searching. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In what way is `reshape` not sufficient?

Comment: @excaza cause with reshape(A,[6,2]) the result will be 1 6 / 2 7 and so on

Comment: Because MATLAB is column-major, not row-major. The need to transpose is addressed in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape fills the output array column-wise, so you want to reshape to a 2x5 array, then transpose:

```
>> A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
>> reshape(A,2,[]).'
ans =
    1    2
    3    4
    5    6
    7    8
    9   10
```